# Конкатенация самой переменной

Tags: javascript, reactjs, form, форма, react-hook

Всем привет. Работаю с формами в react и двумя библиотеками - react-hook-form и yup
Yup помогает легко настраивать валидацию полей, но знать  эти библиотечки для моего вопроса не нужно. Вопрос такой.

Есть некоторое количество селектов, сделанных с помощью material ui
Селекты мапятся из стора.

```
   {createUserRoleStore.rolesQuantity.map((elem, index)=>{
                                        return(



                                                <TableRow key={elem.id}>
                                                    <TableCell>

                                                        <FormControl className='customSelect' variant="standard" fullWidth>

                                                            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Выбрать роль</InputLabel>
                                                            <Select
                                                                {...register(`roleItem${index}`)}
                                                                labelId='roleItem'
                                                                id="roleItem"
                                                                value={createUserRoleStore.rolesQuantity[index].roleTitle}
                                                                label="roleItem"
                                                                onChange={(e)=>createUserRoleStore.handleChange(index, e.target.value)}
                                                                error={!!errors.roleItem}
                                                                helperText={errors?.roleItem?.message}
                                                            >
                                                                {createUserRoleStore.rolesList.map(elem=><MenuItem key={elem.id} value={elem.title}>{elem.title}</MenuItem>)}

                                                            </Select>
                                                        </FormControl>

                                                    </TableCell>
                                                </TableRow>

                                        )
                                    })}
```

Строчка error={!!errors.roleItem} отвечает за корректное отображение ошибок, которое прописывается отдельно. Опустим это.

Дело в том, что этих селектов может быть пять, а может быть десять, и  для каждого селекта строчка {!!errors.roleItem} должна быть уникальной, т.е это должно выглядеть вот таким образом:

```
{!!errors.roleItem0}{!!errors.roleItem1}{!!errors.roleItem2}{!!errors.roleItem3}
```

и т.д. Но как это сделать -  я не знаю. Как можно при передаче пропса в компонент при переборке его изменить?

`{!!errors.roleItem[index]}` не работает. Пробовал по всякому. Буду крайне признателен всем, кто ответит на мой вопрос.

Comment: `errors[index]` чем не гоже?

Comment: @Фитц Чивэл errors[index] - тогда  react  будет перекидывать  index, но если другого варианта вообще нет, то можно и так.  Ключ всегда уникален, но ключ - это что-то, что существует в контексте, вашего roleItem[index] - допустим - roleItem0 не существует. Обычно для таких случаев бывает  id, но в вашем случае похоже  его нет. Я не проверял, но что, если в key   map  прогнать кастомный массив из  id  равный длине вашего errors

Comment: не работает конструкция error={!!errors.roleItem[index]}
Попробовал в самую первую очередь когда делал. Ошибка: https://imgur.com/a/bDxA0iJ

Comment: Фитц Чивэл Если вы внимательно прочли, то !!errors.roleItem[index] не существует, ключ должен быть в контексте, прочтите еще раз.

Comment: Ничего не понимаю, причем тут контекст? Мне же нужно, чтобы при каждом переборе массива, в компоненту <Select> пробрасывался уникальный элемент объекта errors.

Вот укороченный вариант как это должно быть.
<Select error={!!errors.roleItem1}></Select>
<Select error={!!errors.roleItem2}></Select>
<Select error={!!errors.roleItem3}></Select>
<Select error={!!errors.roleItem4}></Select>

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение:

```
error={!!errors[`roleItem${index}`]}
```